# Invoke extension method via reflection (Type.InvokeMember)

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods

Is there a way to invoke extension method like usual (member) method using Type.InvokeMember method? Here is for member methods [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You have to find the static class declaring the extension method, and invoke the static method that way.

Extension methods are just syntactic sugar - there's the [`ExtensionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx) applied to it, but that's all. The CLR really doesn't care about them, and code which calls them is exactly equivalent to calling the method via the declaring type.

In particular, which extension method is picked is partly determined by the namespaces which have been imported - which isn't a concept which is present in the reflection API to start with.